# Grails If Statement not working?

Tags: grails, if-statement, view

I am currently trying to implement a nested if statement on a view in my Grails application. I have the code below which firstly checks to to if a value is true and if so it renders some code (this works). Then if this is not true it falls into the else statement, in here I need a nested If Statement to look at a value and render a different piece of code based on the value.

```
<g:if test="${a?.staticValue == true}">
    <g:field type="text" name="staticText" readonly="true" value="${a?.data}"/>
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:if test="${a?.type == 'Door'}">
        <g:field type="text" name="doorField" value="" placeholder="${a?.wood}"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:elseif test="${a?.type == 'Floor'}">
        <g:field type="text" name="floorField" value="" placeholder="${a?.laminate}"/>
    </g:elseif>
    <g:elseif test="${a?.type == 'Window'}">
        <g:field type="text" name="windowField" value="" placeholder="${a?.blinds}"/>
    </g:elseif>
</g:else>
```

Nothing gets rendered within the else statement and only the first box is shown so the nested if statements do not work for some reason and I don’t understand why. If I remove the if statement at the bottom and run the code below the value show "Door".

```
<g:field type="text" name="typeField" value="" placeholder="${a?.type}"/>
```

I don’t understand why this isn’t working and I am probably missing something silly but would really appreciate the help on this.

Thanks in advance

---

****EDIT*************

---

So I have changed my code as suggested below to trim any white-space even though there shouldn’t be any and I get a weird error:

```
<g:if test="${a?.type.trim().equals('Door')}">
```

The error below seems to suggest that there is no data being pulled:

```
No signature of method: com.smstool.Dynam$VarType.trim() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

This is weird because I have added this else statement to the end and this return the value of "Door" to the view:

```
<g:else>
     ${a?.type}
</g:else>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what may be going on here as im confused :S Thanks

Comment: `.type` is a String instance, right?

Comment: if `a` is falsy then nothing gets rendered. Add `<g:else>${a}</g:else>` after all `<g:elseif>...`

Comment: move this logic into a taglib and then you can unit test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: if a?.staticValue is String try old java way:

```
 <g:if test="${a?.staticValue}">
        <g:field type="text" name="staticText" readonly="true" value="${a?.data}"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>

    <g:if test="${a?.type.toString().equals('Door')}">
        <g:field type="text" name="doorField" value="" placeholder="${a?.wood}"/>
    </g:if>
    <g:elseif test="${a?.type.equals('Floor')}">
        <g:field type="text" name="floorField" value="" placeholder="${a?.laminate}"/>
    </g:elseif>
    <g:elseif test="${a?.type.equals('Window')}">
        <g:field type="text" name="windowField" value="" placeholder="${a?.blinds}"/>
    </g:elseif>
    </g:else>
```

for case insensitive:

**equals** can be changed to : **equalsIgnoreCase**

Comment: So now i have the elseif's and then changed the last one to just else and put this in for testing ${a?.type} and the value returns "Door" so dont understand why it doesn’t fall into the first if statement?

Comment: can you check if your Door string is having some trailing spaces, try trim or something?
added a trim on the first condition, not sure if it is exactly your issue but give it a try
:)

Comment: Hi I have tried the suggested code above and edited my question with the results.

Comment: Something wrong with your value a.type as == should also work, even using .equals is a good practice, try adding a toString(), not sure but let try, I have updated my answer with first conditional statement using toString()

Comment: Thanks the toString worked like a charm, not that I understand it though as its a string on the Domain side :S